# Select All projectnames with a request parameter "All" from UI

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Am passing a request parameter from UI like below

http://localhost:8080/BugReport/home?projectName=ALL

If i pass request parameter=ALL, then it should select all the columns for all the projects from DB.

I tried like below

```
String projectNameStr = request.getParameter("projectName");

    if (projectNameStr != null && !projectNameStr.equals("")) {
            
                if (projectNameStr.equalsIgnoreCase("ALL")) {

    String query = "select b.bug_id,b.creation_ts,b.cf_customer,b.cf_backend_frontend,b.cf_department,p.login_name,b.priority,b.bug_severity,b.bug_status,b.cf_changelist_no,b.cf_cobrand_changelist,b.cf_ps_project_name from bugs b, profiles p where " ";
```

The DB Schema and selecting columns are here proper. Am selecting all the columns but am not getting how to write where condition to select all these columns from all the projects.

Am new to Java & SQL. Can someone help me to write where query here?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: How to write a `WHERE` condition that doesn't restrict the result to only projects with a certain name: ***Omit the `WHERE` clause***, aka remove it, don't write it, get rid of it, etc.

Comment: There is a couple of solutions. `WHERE @projectName IN (tablename.projectname, 'ALL')`. Or `WHERE (@projectName = tablename.projectname) OR (@projectName = 'ALL')`. Or even UNION ...

Comment: Thanks @Akina - Can you please tell me how to replace the requestparameter string value with the above mentioned where condition?